# ROC, variables, unbalanced data, where to start?

Tags: r, logistic

Can someone explain to me how you would know which variables to remove? And how do you know if something is accurate or not? Because when I plot an ROC curve the specificity/sensitivity curve, it looks like a square for a random forest.

If I use 2 different models, I assume I would have to use the same variables if I did stepAIC(logistic regression model) and then use those exact same variables for the random forest?

I have 3 unbalanced datasets that come from the same sample and I have to make something of it and I am not too sure where to start. Thanks!

Comment: If your ROC curve is a perfect square, i.e. your curve passes through the point $(0, 1)$, you have a perfect model that separates both classes.

Answer (score 0):

If your datasets are unbalanced, variable selection can be tricky. You need some measure of the miss-classification costs. See http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~elkan/kddbianca.pdf
for a way this problem was solved.
Edit: I did not see that the earlier post too referred to step wise logistic regression.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Ive tried stepwise logistic regression and random forest. Im just not sure of what to make of my results. Im trying to classify spam data, would feature selection of the most important variables be a better idea? The misclassification rate sounds great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, just wanted to add my two cents of caution about using misclassification rate for unbalanced datasets. If the minority class is really really rare - like 1 % or 2%, then miss-classification rate is not a good measure. If you simply classify everything as the majority class you would be right a very high percentage of the time. So I assume that your case is not that unbalanced.